# Why is same command different in IPython-Notebook and Python?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've tried

```
print(all(x for x in [0,1]))
```

in normal Python and as expected I get `False`. However in the IPython-Notebook 2.0.0-b1 I get the result

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000738EDC8>
```

and I have no idea how to get `False` as before.

Any suggestions? Why does IPython not consume my generator? (it actually does work if I convert the generator into a list by hand or if I use the console IPython)

EDIT: Since someone couldn't replicate it, I tried something out and solved the issue:
If you start the notebook with `--pylab inline`, it will import `numpy.all()` into the namespace which shadows the built-in `all()`. This causes the problem!

Comment: I just tried and could not replicate it.

Comment: That's interesting - it gave me and idea and I solved the issue. See EDIT

Comment: Good find! I was under the impression that the numpy module was namespaced to np. you should put this in as an issue on github.